# Override Tekton global PipelineRun timeout

Tags: kubernetes, timeout, openshift, tekton, tekton-pipelines

I have a problem where i need to trigger multiple Pipelinerun's at same time where the runs will take longer the 1 hour. The global timeout for the PipelineRun is 1 hours by default so it fails. The team managing the Openshift cluster does not want to change the global timeout so I have to override it in some way.

The resources I am using is an EventListener, TriggerBinding, TriggerTemplate, Pipeline and PipelineRun.

I have tried to set a timeout on the Pipeline tasks like:

```
      runAfter:
        - fetch-repository
      taskRef:
        kind: ClusterTask
        name: buildah
      timeout: "3h0m0s"
```

but the PipelineRun timeout seems to have precedence so it does not work.

- Openshift version: 4.9.35
- K8s version: v1.22.8
- Tekton seems to be
  installed with Openshift and cannot find which version but probably
  very new.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with OpenShift, I have a feature request filed with redhat support about this ... been over a year now ...

Although you mentioned using EventListeners: in that case, you should be able to force your own pipelinerun timeout, setting up your TriggerTemplate.

Try this:

```
apiVersion: triggers.tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: TriggerTemplate
metadata:
  name: foo
spec:
  [...]
  resourcetemplates:
  - apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
    kind: PipelineRun
    metadata:
      generateName: foo-
    spec:
      timeout: 2h30m0s
      [...]
```

The only issue with this, is that you can't use them from OpenShift console. You would need to make sure your EventListener is used, starting that pipeline (eg: with curl, an oc plugin, ...), enforcing proper timeout configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will definitely try to create a certain PipelineRun resource for the nightly builds that is called from the TriggerTemplate instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a timeout in the PipelineRun:

```
spec:
  ...
  timeout: 12h0m0s
```

If you set it to 0, it will fail immediately upon encountering an error. For now it works on OpenShift Pipelines, but it might get deprecated [as in Tekton](https://tekton.dev/docs/pipelines/pipelineruns/#configuring-a-failure-timeout) (not fully deprecated, just syntax change).